# Jupyter Notebook Hinterland Autotyping

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Hinterland for Jupyter for its autocomplete feature. However, I'm noticing that it has a tendency to actually complete things as I am typing them. For example, if I want to type "variable" and it recognizes the name, it will add the "iable" sometimes if I have only typed "var". I looked through the settings and documentation, but I haven't been able to solve this (feel like I'm missing something obvious). Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Hi, the same issue bothers me a lot too. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Not yet - still looking for a solution to this. Playing around with the regex in the settings doesn't affect this behavior it looks like